# Showing that the functional dot product must be positive.

Tags: functional-analysis

The Question:

Given $Lu=-u''$ with $D(L)=\{u(x)|u \in C^2 [0,1], u(0)=0, u(1)=u'(1)\},$ show that $\langle Lu,u \rangle \geq 0$ for all $u \in D(L)$ where

$$
\langle f,g \rangle =\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx.
$$

My attempt:

I did integration by parts to get the expression

$$
-u'(1)^2 + \int_{0}^{1} u'(x)^2 dx
$$
I then attempted Simpson's Rule on the integral to try and show that the integral must be larger than $u'(1)^2$ but that doesn't seem to work. I think using a cubic spline might work but that seems like more trouble than it's worth. Any hints (please just a *hint*) on where to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, sorry. That's a typo on my part. It is that $Lu=-u''.$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hint: a certain inequality regarding inner products might help.

Comment: Do I apply this inequality to $-u'(1)^2 + \int$ or do I start over at the definition?

Comment: It's really just the same hint as Suspicious Fred's. Either way you use the same inequality. Hint: remember that $1 = \int_0^1 1 \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Ah. The cousin of adding zero: multiplying by 1. Thanks, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : use $u'(1)^2= u(1)^2 = (\int_0^1 u'(x)dx)^2$ and an inequality on inner products.